# meaning of "loads"

Tags: meaning

An English coach says

> I failed my first two
>   driving exams I do think that learning
>   to drive is like learning a language
>   you can't just study **loads** and pick it
>   up in one day it's a slow process

I guess "**loads**" here mean some kind of English learning materials, e.g. books, videos, exercises, etc. It seems like something like stuff. Is my understanding right?

Answer (score 3):

No, I'm afraid not.

From dictionary.com :

*loads, Informal. a great quantity or number:* 
*loads of fun; loads of people.*

It's just a colloquial way of saying *study a lot.*

Comment: So, "loads" in that example plays a role of adverb?

Comment: I suppose it does, yes.